# How do you do text to Columns & Unpivoting at the same time in python?? using Pandas maybe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, unpivot

I want to make this:

[image]

Into This:
[image]

I already have the first table in a data frame in python as df3. How do I get what the output I want using pandas preferably in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
  ID Invoice     DO other_cols
0  A       a  1,2,3        xxx
1  B       b    4,5        xxx
2  C       c      6        xxx
```

You could use `assign`+`str.split` to transform your string into list, and `explode` to generate one row per item in the list:

```
(df.assign(DO=df['DO'].str.split(','))
   .explode('DO')
)
```

output:

```
  ID Invoice DO other_cols
0  A       a  1        xxx
0  A       a  2        xxx
0  A       a  3        xxx
1  B       b  4        xxx
1  B       b  5        xxx
2  C       c  6        xxx
```

Comment: thx, couldn't find one easily, do you have a script to find them? or just good memory ;)

Comment: google `pandas explode splitted` ;)